# Noninferiority in a multilevel model

Tags: r, panel-data, sas, non-inferiority

I am working on a randomized trial in which patients were randomized to one of two groups and followed over time, they were assessed at 5 time points including baseline. The outcomes include continuous measures (amount of pain) and dichotomous ones (various side effects).

Ordinarily, I would use multilevel models (linear or nonlinear).

However, here, the main interest is in noninferiority of one treatment to the other. I am aware of TOST (two one sided t-tests) and I could do those at each time point, at least for the continuous dependent variable (and probably as proportions for the categorical ones).  I have not seen a noninferiority method for multilevel models in software that I use (mostly SAS and I strongly prefer SAS, but I also have R available).

I could do both the regular (test of differences) multilevel models and the TOST, but I am just figured I would try and confirm my intuition that this would be reasonable.

Comment: Do you want to assess NI just for the final time point for both outcomes, or at the 4 post-baseline time points (=8 comparisons?)?

Comment: I guess most brutal method to get a 2.5% one-sided signficance level: Get naive (=ignoring the correlation of the time points) (100-2.5/8)% one-sided confidence limits at each time point and declare for any time point, where the NI meets the criteria. Or the approach of requiring NI at all 8 comparisons, for which one could use naive 97.5% confidence limits. I guess one should be able to get confidence intervals that take the correlation across time points into account.

Comment: Probably just final time point - which might solve my problem.  Thanks.